# Get data from garmin API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, garmin

I have issue with get data from **garmin API** in rails.
I login sucessful but i don't get anything data from garmin.
What errors here? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the garmin api documentation provided by garmin when you registered your application. The all possible features for fetching the data will be listed in the documentation